# Get script location from server

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller (spring), that returns application version ("`version/get`") and I need use this version to specify location of js-file:

```
<script src="/r/{{appVersion}}/js/app.js"></script>
```

How can I do this using javascript or angularjs?

I tried to do something like this:

```
module.controller('ResourceLoaderController', [
    '$rootScope', '$scope', '$http',
    function ($rootScope, $scope, $http) {
        'use strict';

        $scope.getVersion = function() {
            $http.get('/version/get').then(function (response) {
                $rootScope.appVer = response.data;
            });
        };

        $scope.getVersion();
    }]);
```

And then:

```
<script src="js/controllers/ResourceLoaderController.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="ResourceLoaderController">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/r/{{appVer.text}}/css/app.css" charset="utf-8">
    <script src="/r/{{appVer.text}}/js/app.js"></script>
</div>
```

But I can't use `<div>` in header...

Comment: You might want to see [this documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource).

Comment: will it be ok if dynamically create the script tag?

Comment: Partially... It,s created, but I have other angular controllers in app.js and they are became undefined in runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this inside your `$http` success.

```
// use global document since Angular's $document is weak
var s = document.createElement('script'); 
s.src = '/r/'+response.data.text+'/js/app.js';
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

It will create a new script element with proper src.

> Angular processes the web page only after the page has been loaded and
>   built by which time the `<script>` tag has been processed its one time
>   (script tags are only ever run once). Other tags such as `img` will
>   change the visual appearance of the screen when their properties
>   change after the page has loaded ... but as mentioned, the script is
>   only processed once and even then during page load and before Angular
>   can ever get control.

So you need to append your script tag. Or you may achieve this by server side coding.

Comment: You can have a look here also. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27306706/how-to-bind-script-elements-src-attribute-in-angularjs

Comment: Thank you for answer. This works, but I include other angular controllers in app.js and get a error that this controllers are undefined.

Answer (score 3):

I think this might just work,

**1**. Have a `script` tag and `link` tag, provide them certain Ids,

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" charset="utf-8" id="theCSS">
    <script src="" id="theScript"></script>`

**2**. Modify your controller to look like,

```
module.controller('ResourceLoaderController', [
    '$rootScope', '$scope', '$http',
    function ($rootScope, $scope, $http) {
        'use strict';

        $scope.getVersion = function() {
            $http.get('/version/get').then(function (response) {
               // $rootScope.appVer = response.data;
               var scriptElement = angular.element(document.querySelector( '#theScript'));
               scriptElement.src = '/r/' + response.data.text +'/js/app.js';
              var cssElement = angular.element(document.querySelector( '#theCSS'));
               cssElement.href = '/r/' + response.data.text +'/css/app.css';
            });
        };

        $scope.getVersion();
    }]);
```

Put the ng-controller attribute in the html tag / head tag.

Alternatively try creating the script and css tags dynamically.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I included app.js but it contains other angular.js controllers an I get an error in runtime that this controllers are undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You should inject the script dynamically like:

```
$scope.getVersion = function() {
    $http.get('/version/get').then(function (response) {
        $rootScope.appVer = response.data;
        var myScript = document.createElement('script');
        myScript.type ='text/javascript';
        myScript.async ='true';
        myScript.src = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/r/" + response.data + "/js/app.js"
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(myScript);
    });
};

$scope.getVersion();
```