# Include javascript external file if allowed in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need to define for my html page that load a javascript external file only when the variable `$scope.jsallowed` is set to `true`, So I tried this code: (My page is based on AngularJS )
In html :

```
<script src="assets/js/slider.min.js" data-ng-if="jsallowed"></script>
```

In JS:

```
$scope.jsallowed = false;
```

(Note that I set the application and controller and... but I just included codes you need here.)
But the problem is, My javascript file loads yet. While it should not. How can I improve my code to prevent loading it until I set jsallowed variable to true?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27306744/1132354

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately that data-ng-if="jsallowed" won't do the trick you're looking for. What you can do, instead, is loading the script asynchronously directly inside your JavaScript file with something like this:

```
<script>
var resource = document.createElement('script'); 
resource.src = "assets/js/slider.min.js";
var script = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
script.parentNode.insertBefore(resource, script);
</script>
```

Comment: How about wrapping this code in directive, doing some whatever magic there? Why downvoted, just curious, because not angular way suggested? Can we play the `$injector` here, to dynamically add stuff?

Comment: @user3198882, there is no Angular way to do this trick. Not sure why you down voted my suggestion but I can assure this works and it's quite common to see this syntax around. Also, this is what Google suggests when importing its Analytics library. Of course, you can wrap that inside an Angular directive, I just highlighted the JavaScript code you need to run to do the trick.

Comment: It wasn't me, who downvoted, I just asked why someone did it, still interesting to me as well :)

Comment: Thank you too much, I tried this in an non-angularjs page and It worked well, I want to know, Will pure javascript codes work in angularjs-based pages as well?
UPDATE: I tried it in my AngularJS page and It worked well!

Comment: That's right, Angular is a JavaScript framework which means you can use pure JavaScript code in any Angular project. Angular just add/extend native JavaScript functionalities to do more with less.

Comment: So I can put into my `<head>` something like this `<my-script ng-if="expression" ng-src="expression"></my-script>`, then watch `ng-if` expression in `myScript` directive and do like `$element[0].parentNode.insertBefore(resource, $element[0])`, sorry for non-angular DOM manips. No magical quirks, if do this way?

Comment: No, Angular cannot control directives present in the head of the document, only inside the body. However, you can use that directive before closing your </body> tag in the page and the result will be the same.
When you include a script inside the <head>, the broweser will load and run that script before the page is ready. If you include an Angular syntax in there your browser will not recognize that code at that point.