# Google Maps API dynamic load with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to load Google Maps API using AngularJS:

```
<html data-ng-app="search-app">
<head data-ng-controller="GoogleMaps">
    <script ng-src="{{mapsUrl}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
....
</head>
```

and controller for that part:

```
search.controller('GoogleMaps', [
    '$scope','$sce',
    function GoogleMaps($scope,$sce) {
        var mapsUrl = '//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&key=my_api_key';
        $scope.mapsUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(mapsUrl);
    }
]);
```

but when the Google Map API is called within the search controller it throws and error

> this.setMap is not a function

for

```
function CustomMarker(latlng, map, args) {
    this.latlng = latlng;
    this.args = args;
    this.setMap(map);
}
```

but when I will replace `{{mapsUrl}}` with full URL in the HTML header it will works.

Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended up appending URL to the header as a script on load event

```
function require(url, callback)
{
    var element = document.createElement("script");
    element.src = url;
    element.type="text/javascript";
    element.addEventListener('load', callback);
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(e);
}
```