# How can we use background animations like vantajs or particles.js in angular application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I tried this and didn't work

```
<div id="vantajs"></div>
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/100/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.vantajs.com/dist/vanta.birds.min.js"></script>
<script> 

VANTA.BIRDS({
  el: "#vantajs",  
})
</script>
```

[How to bind <script> element's src attribute in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27306706/how-to-bind-script-elements-src-attribute-in-angularjs)

According to this we cannot use script tag

Is there any other way to add vantajs ?

Comment: Like any other plain javascript library, it can be imported regularly and used in angular like you would use any other (jQuery and so on).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add `vanta.js` in your `angular.json`, script object.
2. declare variable where you want to use that js for e.g. app.component.ts

   ```
   import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
   declare var VANTA;
   @Component({
        selector: 'my-app',
        templateUrl: './app.component.html',
        styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
   })

   export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {   
   name = 'Angular';

        ngOnInit() {

             VANTA.CELLS({
                  el: "#your-element-selector"
             })

         }

   }
   ```

Comment: Error : cannot find #your-element-selector         //I use    id="your-element-selector"

Comment: Initialize VANTA in ngOnInit hook, not in the constructor as constructor get call first then HTML renders. (see I've updated my answer)

Comment: For those who want a simple example of how to setup and use Vanta.js in Angular(14.2 as of writing this). Here's the repo containing the code. https://github.com/chinonso098/simple-vantajs-example-angular